How to solve QJSEngine.evaluate blocking execution
I have a QT C++ application that I have upgraded to use the new QJSEngine in QT 6.7.1. My application is single threaded and what I found was the QJSEngine.evaluate blocks and does not process the application event loop so if I have a miss behaving script my application locks up. I did move the QJSEngine to a separate thread but then I learned that many/most of the invocable class members would cause my application to crash, from what I have read calling across threads is something I should not do. If I run QJSEngine in the main thread everything functions as it should except for this blocking issue.
I am looking for any advice on how to deal with this issue, maybe there is something fundamental I am missing. Are there third party scripting tools that would be a better solution?
My application is used for instrument control and scripts are written by customers that use functionality exposed through invokable functions in java script to solve their specific problem.
I created a class that contains the QJSEngine and then moved this to a new thread and use signals and slots to integrate into the main thread. In the parent class that starts the script are a number of invokable functions. I have included some of the code that may help illustrate what I am doing.
I create an instance of this class and move it to a new thread
class JSengine : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QJSEngine engine;
    QString   script;
    QJSValue  result;
    bool      isRunning = false;

public slots:
    QJSValue runEngine(void)
    {
        isRunning = true;
        result = engine.evaluate(script);
        emit resultReady(result);
        isRunning = false;
        return result;
    }

signals:
    void resultReady(QJSValue result);
};


Here I create an instance of my class and reference my invokable functions.
    engine = new JSengine();
    QJSValue mips = engine->engine.newQObject(p);
    engine->engine.globalObject().setProperty("mips",mips);


This is the code that moves the JSengine to a new thread and starts execution
    engine->script = script;
    connect(engine,&JSengine::resultReady,this,&ScriptingConsole::scriptFinished);
    thread = new QThread(this);
    engine->moveToThread(thread);
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(engineDone()));
    connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), engine, SLOT(runEngine()));
    thread->start();


All of this functions and I can terminate a script by interrupting the execution and then terminating the thread.
    engine->engine.setInterrupted(true);
    thread->terminate();


As soon as I call one of the invokable functions my application crashes.
